# Wireless Card not detected?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, inspiron

I opened up my Laptop and I can see the Wireless Card installed. [The hardware]. Yet I don't see it working.

Here's a screenshot
 [Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mfkq3n&s=5)

Wi-fi device is {none}. What does this mean? Does it mean that my network card is broken or something? What are the possible solutions?

Also, I remember I ran the BIOS setup from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/inspiron-1545). I had changed the operating system, and was installing all the drivers, and with all the audio/video drivers, I ran BIOS too. But I guess, after that, my wireless did work for a decent span of time, and then I turned on to Ubuntu, and it stopped working. I am not sure if this is relevant at all or not. But just informing. 
I am using Dell Inspiron 1545.

Output of

```
kraken@kraken-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for kraken: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 13
       serial: 00:23:ae:34:46:d2
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff ioport:de00(size=256)

kraken@kraken-Inspiron-1545:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

Comment: Stupid question: Have you tried to turn on your wireless adapter with F2 Key (or whatever key it is on an Inspiron)?

Comment: yes I have. The bluetooth works but the wireless not.

Answer (score 1):

If BIOS is not detecting the device, then it is a pure hardware issue irrespective of OS. `lspci` is not detecting your hardware. So yes, most probably it is broken.

Comment: Or not installed...